# Install Microsoft SQL Server on Pop!_OS

Tags: database, sql-server, apt-get, repository, pop-os

I am trying to install Microsoft SQL Server on the latest Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (jammy) but receiving following errors:

```
sudo apt-get install mssql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I was also not able to add the repository using the information given at [microsoft sql server link for Ubuntu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16) :

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
```

Can someone guide me on how to resolve these dependencies and install MS Sql Server on Pop!_OS?

**Edit:**

I also installed `Synaptic` and then tried installing `mssql-server` but got the following error as shown in image:

[image: Synaptic]

Comment: Does this information, [Warning: apt-key is deprecated.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992799/warning-apt-key-is-deprecated-manage-keyring-files-in-trusted-gpg-d-instead), get you past the warning?

Comment: Nope. It does not!

Comment: You will need to provide more information on the reason that is the case, because, after reading the answer to that question it is my firm believe it should resolve the warning.

Comment: Some additional reading: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: @Ramhound i installed `Synaptic` and tried installing `mssql-server` from there, but got the following error. Does this help in understanding the problem?

Comment: If you ran `sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-preview.list)"` then you ran the incorrect command if you are running 22.04. A proper package for 22.04 does exist though.  `mssql-server-preview.list` is the wrong file you should be using `prod.list` instead. FYI: **The warning is just warning, you imported the GPG keys, you just did it in an insecure way.**

Comment: I am not using Ubuntu but Pop!_OS, but was trying with the ubuntu instructions on docs.microsoft.com...i guess i was wrong...

Comment: The instructions for Ubuntu should absolutely work on Pop!_OS, you just have to use the correct instructions, the support article points to the wrong distro list file.

Comment: where can i find these instructions? i googled but could not locate one.

Comment: Well I am sort of just telling you what you need to do.  You need to point to the correct version (22.04) and `prod.list` instead of `mssql-server-preview.list`